# Rails Query Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am fairly new to Rails and understand the basics of joins and associations but I am having a challenge with how to best use rails for some general queries. There is a lot of documentation I have reviewed but still not clear on best approach for this query. The models are as follows

User:

```
has_many :accounts
```

Account:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :address, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => 'address_id'
```

Address:

```
belongs_to :account  (This is really a many to one relationship where an address,
                      can belong to more than one account)
```

The query is to find all account addresses for the user.  A standard sql query would look something like this.

```
SELECT Users.ID AS Users_ID, Users.Username, Account.acct_name, Address.*
FROM Address INNER JOIN (Users INNER JOIN Account ON Users.ID = Account.user_id) 
ON Address.ID = Account.address_id
WHERE (((Users.ID)=2));
```

There seems to be a lot of power in rails to do this without a direct sql query.  What is the best approach to doing this and are the models correct?  Is the foreign key representation in the correct model.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a [**has_many :through** association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

```
class User < AR::B
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :addresses, through: :accounts
end
```

You can then query all addresses of the user with `@user.addresses`.

If you want to take a look at the SQL query that ActiveRecord generates for your query, you may call [**`.to_sql`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-to_sql) on a query: `@user.addresses.to_sql`.

**Edit**: Regarding the rest of your associations setup, you'll need to rework how Address and Account are joined. One approach might be this one.

```
class Account < AR::B
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :address # the accounts table should have an address_id integer column
end

class Address < AR::B
  has_many :accounts
end
```

For more info on the options you can pass to the associations, see the [Rails API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: Account does have an address_id integer column.  I am assuming your stating that the foreign key notation is not necessary as it is address_id

Comment: Right, it should not be nescessary to specify any additional `foreign_key` here if you adhere to Rails conventions.

Comment: I think I have just hit a wall as I had tried through before with an different schema.  Thank for clarification on this.

Comment: Thomas,  in my sql query I am returning the account name with the addresses.  @user.addresses will not return that field as it is only pulling from the address table.

Comment: You can try the `.includes` method here. `@user.accounts.includes(:addresses)`. This query should load all the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, based on what you've described, the Address class should probably have the relationship has_many :accounts rather than belongs_to :account. The general rule of thumb is to use belongs_to when there's a foreign key in that model's table for the belongs_to table. But for this query that really doesn't matter, as you're starting from users.

Something like this should be close to what you want:

```
User.where(:id => 2).includes(:accounts => :addresses)
```

See the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for more information. The squeel gem is also useful for even more advanced querying capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I ever get to 15 I will up vote this response.  Thank for the tip on squeel gem.  I will take a look at it.